# Scrollable Listbox

Tags: zk

I want see the items of list box on scroll, On ZK site I found only way to do it is set height in Pixels or set the rows property to specific number of rows. but I want to set it according to the screen size is there any way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the [BorderLayout](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Layouts/Borderlayout) to lay your components. Add your list to the center and it will display a scroll bar. Read about layouts (size, vflex etc.) first because they can be really tricky.

[And read this also](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Essentials/Laying%20out%20Your%20ZK%20Components)